# executing query inside column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

I have a table A with columns 1.Column 1 contains a query select * from tableD;

I need to execute the query inside column1 using single query if possible..How to do this..

Database is netezza.If u provide ans for oracle Db also fine.

Answer (score 1):

This seems Dynamic query problem for me .. 
In Oracle you can create a procedure to call this query which is actually stored in a table.

In my knowledge you can not directly run query stored as text.

You need to create a procedure or function where you can call this query as dynamically with `execute immediate` command.